# Laravel dabatabse facade memory usage

Tags: php, laravel, memory, pdo

I've found great example written in php pdo, which helps to iterate huge amount of data without actually allocating memory for whole set of results:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * from playlists limit 50000';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();

    while (($result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
        //do something
    }
```

I've done an investigation and this approach uses `18mb` of memory.

If I fetch all results like this `$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` memory usage upraises to `35mb`.

Using laravel's `illuminate/database` component and very similar approach `DB::table('playlists')->limit(50000)->get();` also uses `35mb` of memory.

- How can I achieve first approach using Laravel's eloquent or DB facade?
- Could you suggest some articles how this difference in memory usage develops?

Thanks

Comment: Are you comparing like with like? The Laravel framework has overheads of its own. Check memory usage of Laravel without doing the query and check how much memory usage increased when doing the query. Compare that to memory usage without Laravel before and after doing the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute an SQL query with php (either mysql functions or PDO) all data returned from query loads in to memory as a "result set".

In order to use data in "result set" you have to fetch them in regular php arrays/objects.

**PDOStatement::fetch** - fetches one row from the result set in to memory.

**PDOStatement::fetchAll** - fetches all rows from result set to memory thus doubling the memory usage.

Eloquent has ability to [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#chunking-results) result sets. This is equivalent to performing "X times fetch" in PDO.

However, if you are working with very large result sets consider using SQL limits.

Comment: Let's say I chunk by 100. So every chunk execution will allocate memory for 100 rows or just one?

Comment: @EvaldasButkus Every chunk execution loads 100 rows to memory at once. At second chunk, first chunk gets overridden by second chunk. So peak memory usage should be result set + chunk size theoretically.

Answer (score 3):

The Laravel approach to processing large data sets like this is to use [chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results).

```
DB::table('playlists')->chunk(1000, function($playlists) use($count) {
    foreach($playlists as $playlist) {
        // do something with this playlist
    }
});
```

This ensures that no more than the chunk size (in my example, 1000 rows) is loaded into RAM at once. 1k is arbitrary; you could chunk 1, 100, 253, etc.

Comment: If you want to cap it at 50k rows max, you'd need to do a little logic to keep track of iterations within the loop.